# Azure VM "Running (Provisioning timed out)"

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

We have migrated VM from VMware to Azure. It's working fine but the warning message is being shown "Running (Provisioning timed out)" (http://prntscr.com/6aff45), which is the only wrong thing with it.

Migration was made by these rough steps:
IDE Drivers reinstalled, exporting as image, converting to VHD and uploading to Azure. (Cannot give you more details as migration was made not by me and it was a long time ago so he cannot remember the details)

What could be the cause of this message and what can I do?

**Additional info**
**VM Windows edition**: *Windows Server 2008 R2 Standart - Service Pack 1*

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a copy of my VM ( captured VM without sysprep and generalization ) and created a new VM using that image. That magically worked.

Answer (score 2):

was the image sysprepped before being uploaded to Azure?

Do these things:

1. Log out and log back in to the admin portal. Check if the error message refreshed.
2. Remove the VHD as an image and just add it back as a Disk with Operating System. Then boot the disk and run sysprep /generalize. Then capture the VM as an image.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes, it was sysprepped.